# PySVN - Determine if a repository exists

Tags: python, svn, repository, exists

I'm writing a small script that manages several SVN repositories. Users pass through the ID of the repository they want to change (the root of the repos are of the form https://www.mydomain.com/).

I need to check if the given repo actually exists. I've tried using `Client.list` to see if I can find any files, like so:

```
client = pysvn.Client()
client.list("https://.../<username>/")
```

But if the repo does not exist then the script hangs on the list line. From digging through the tracebacks it looks like pysvn is actually hanging on the login credentials callback (client.callback_get_login - which I have implemented but omitted, it does not fail if the repo exists).

Can you suggest how I can determine if a repo exists or not using pysvn?

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce your *hanging in credentials callback* problem, so it might need an expanded description of the problem. I'm running pysvn 1.7.2 on Ubuntu 10.04, Python 2.6.6.

When I try to list a non-existent remote repository with `client.list()` it raises an exception.  You could also use `client.info2()` to check for existence of a remote repository:

```
head_rev = pysvn.Revision(pysvn.opt_revision_kind.head)
bad_repo = 'https://.../xyz_i_dont_exist'
good_repo = 'https://.../real_project'
for url in (bad_repo, good_repo):
    try:
        info = client.info2(url, revision=head_rev, recurse=False)
        print url, 'exists.'
    except pysvn._pysvn_2_6.ClientError, ex:
        if 'non-existent' in ex.args[0]:
            print url, 'does not exist'
        else:
            print url, 'error:', ex.args[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Peter,

My team and I have experienced the same challenge. Samplebias, try providing a `callback_get_login` function but set your `callback_server_ssl_trust_prompt` to return `(True, trust_dict['failures'], True)`. IFF subversion has not cached your server certificate trust settings, then you may find the `info2()` (or Peter's `list()` command) hangs (it's not actually hanging, it just takes intermittently much longer time to return). Oddly, when you CTRL-C the interpreter in these scenarios, you'll get indication that it hung on the login callback, not the server_cert verification. Play around with your `~/.subversion/auth` settings (in particular the `svn.simple` and `svn.ssl.server` directories) and you'll see different amounts of 'hang time'. Look at `pysvn.Client.callback_cancel` if you need to handle situations which truly never return.

Considering: http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt you need to decide what your desired behavior is. Do you want ONLY to allow those connections for which you already have a cached trust answer? Or, do you want to ALWAYS accept regardless of server certificate verification (WARNING: this could (obviously) have negative security implications). Consider the following suggestion:

```
import pysvn

URL1 = "https://exists.your.org/svn/repos/dev/trunk/current"
URL2 = "https://doesntexit.your.org/svn/repos/dev/trunk/current"
URL3 = "https://exists.your.org/svn/repos/dev/trunk/youDontHavePermissionsBranch"

ALWAYS = "ALWAYS"
NEVER = "NEVER"

DESIRED_BEHAVIOR = ALWAYS

def ssl_server_certificate_trust_prompt(trust_dict):

if DESIRED_BEHAVIOR == NEVER:
    return (False, 0, False)
elif DESIRED_BEHAVIOR == ALWAYS:
    return (True, trust_dict['failures'], True)
raise Exception, "Unsupported behavior"

def testURL(url):
    try:
        c.info2(url)
        return True
    except pysvn.ClientError, ce:
        if ('non-existant' in ce.args[0]) or ('Host not found' in ce.args[0]):
            return False
        else:
            raise ce

c = pysvn.Client()
c.callback_ssl_server_trust_prompt = lambda t: (False, t['failures'], True)
c.callback_get_login = lambda x, y, z: (True, "uname", "pw", False)

if not testURL(URL1): print "Test1 failed."

if testURL(URL2): print "Test2 failed."
try:
    testURL(URL3)
    print "Test3 failed."
except: pass
```

In actuality, you probably don't want to get as fancy as I have with the return values. I *do* think it was important to consider a potential 403 returned by the server and the "Host not found" scenario separately.

Comment: If the call remains hung unexplained by the code above you may want to implement pysvn.Client.callback_cancel and see what the state of execution is when you get the callback. Otherwise, I'd need to see more specifics about your code/server configuration. Feel free to contact me offline if you like.